# WSO2 ESB MessageStore & MessageProcessor support for RabbitMQ?

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, amqp, wso2-esb

I have tested AMQP Transport implementation for RabbitMQ (v3.3.5) from WSO2 ESB (v4.8.1) Proxies with a few minor issues, now everything works fine. For this, I followed [this](http://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/amqp-transport-for-wso2-esb-based-on-rabbitmq-java-client) blog post (from 2013/03/26).

Now, I would like to try with WSO2 MessageStore & MessageProcessor with RabbitMQ, because I think this is the best approach to follow, but seems that is not any implementation for RabbitMQ and WSO2's Documentation Portal says [nothing](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Custom+Message+Store) of how to implement it.

I know that RabbitMQ (v3.3.5) do not implement JMS1.1 and AMQP1.0 by default, It does need extra plugins. Then, What do I need to follow to implement MS/MP correctly?.

I have started reviewing the source code of the current implementation of org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore and org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor, but I need more guidance.

Someone has implement custom MessageStore/MessageProcessor?, Could you share your experience?.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in existing WSO2 JMS MessageStore implementation, I have created a new JMS-AMQP MessageStore for RabbitMQ. Using WSO2 MessageStore I can manage DeadLetter Channel and GuaranteedDelivery Patterns from WSO2 ESB.

The steps followed were:

1) To solve incompatibility issues between AMQP 0.9.1 implementation of RabbitMQ and JMS 1.1.

Right now does not exist any lib to connect to AMQP Broker using JMS, except the [Apache Qpid client (0.30)](https://qpid.apache.org/components/qpid-jms/index.html). It was a great help.

2) Improve existing code of WSO2 JMS MessageStore.
I added a new second JMS Destination, the first one was to consume and the another one was to produce messages. In this manner I got to connect to RabbitMQ using pre-configured Exchanges, Routing Keys and Queues.

I hope that is useful.
Regards.

Comment: Here the implementation of WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 MessageStore for RabbitMQ:
 
https://github.com/Chilcano/wso2esb-rabbitmq-message-store     

I hope you find this useful.